# How can i prevent exposing my usernames when calling a REST API

Tags: security

I am integrating my asp.net mvc4 web application with a workflow engine, currently to call the engine API and get the JSON results i am performing the following :-

I have the following razor view which have a javaScript which will make the call:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
@section scripts {

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var name = prompt("Please enter your packageid", "JordanEngineersAssociation");

         var fullurl = 'http://localhost:8080/jw/web/json/workflow/process/list?j_username=kermit&hash=9449B5ABCFA9AFDA36B801351ED3DF66&loginAs=@User.Identity.Name&packageId=' + name;
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: fullurl,
             dataType: "JSONP",
             success: function (result) {
                 var arr = ((typeof (result.data) == 'object') &&
                             (result.data.constructor.name == 'Array'))
                      ? result.data
                      : [result.data];
                 $.each(arr, function (key, val) {
                 var str = val.name + ' | Version ' + val.version;
                     $('<li/>', { text: str })
                     .appendTo($('#products'));

                 });
             }
         });

     });
     </script>
}
<h1>All Processes</h1>
<ul id="products">
</ul>
```

The above is working well , but i am concern about how secure is this approach of exposing the current login username to the outside world as part of the API call,, so how i can make my call more secure -if it is not currently secure-?

Best Regards

Comment: Are you constrained from encrypting the name before transmission?

Comment: i do not knwo if this is possibl,